# rubygems doesn't install on push in openshift

Tags: ruby, sinatra, openshift

I'm trying to deploy an app in Openshift that requires some gems, how do I get Openshift to install those when I push via git?

Here's what my `config.ru` file currently looks like:

```
require 'rubygems'

require './app.rb'

run Sinatra::Application
```

And as for `app.rb` it requires the following gems:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'redcarpet'
require 'stringex'
require 'data_uri'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probabily need to add those into a Gemfile like:

```
# Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'stringex'
gem 'data_uri'
```

and run bundle locally before pushing to generate the Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/sinatra.html) for you app

in Gemfile

```
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'stringex'
gem 'data_uri'
```

in config.ru

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'bundler'  

Bundler.require  
require './my_app' 
run Sinatra::Application
```

Start  server with rackup, and Sinatra will be loaded via Bundler.

```
$ rackup
```